# Задача про шарики на python 3

Tags: python, python-2.x

Задачка на питоне:

**Условие:**
В одной компьютерной игре игрок выставляет в линию шарики разных цветов. Когда образуется непрерывная цепочка из трех и более шариков одного цвета, она удаляется из линии. Все шарики при этом сдвигаются друг к другу, и ситуация может повториться.

Напишите программу, которая по данной ситуации определяет, сколько шариков будет сейчас уничтожено. Естественно, непрерывных цепочек из трех и более одноцветных шаров в начальный момент может быть не более одной.

**Входные данные:**
Даны количество шариков в цепочке (не более 10^5 ) и цвета шариков (от 0 до 9, каждому цвету соответствует свое целое число).

**Выходные данные:**
Требуется вывести количество шариков, которое будет уничтожено.

---

**Пример 1:**

входные данные
5 1 3 3 3 2

выходные данные
3

**Пример 2:**

входные данные
10 3 3 2 1 1 1 2 2 3 3

выходные данные
10

---

Написал код:

```
res = 0
s = raw_input().split()
while True:
        res_pr=res
        i = 1
        while i < len(s) - 2:
            if ((s[i]==s[i+1]) and (s[i]==s[i+2])):
                res+=3
                del s[i+2]
                del s[i+1]
                while (s[i]==s[i+1]):
                    res+=1
                    del s[i+1]
                del s[i]
                break
            i+=1
        if res_pr==res:
                break
print(res)
```

На первом примере работает, на втором list index out of range (строка 11)

Что не так?

Comment: сначала 1, 1 и 1, потом 2, 2 и 2 потом 3, 3 ,3 и 3

Comment: 10 будет в выводе

Comment: после удаления шаров правые переезжают на их место

Comment: Из условия:" Когда образуется непрерывная цепочка из трех и более шариков одного цвета, она удаляется из линии. Все шарики при этом сдвигаются друг к другу, и ситуация может повториться."

Comment: Поменяйте или тэг или код. В третьем питоне нет ``raw_input()``

Comment: только сейчас допер. все починил. спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools

min_len = 3 

def schet(kolvo: list, res=0) -> int:
    c = 0
    for num, group in itertools.groupby(kolvo):
        lg = len(list(group)) 
        c += lg
        if lg >= min_len: 
            return schet(kolvo[:c-lg]+kolvo[c:], res+lg)  
    return res



print(schet(input().split()))
```